# multiply each matrix slice in a 3d array by a single matrix in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a 1 x matrix `mat=matrix(1,1,13)`

I also have an array that is 13 x 1000 x 10.

`dfarray = array(1:(13*1000*10),dim=c(13,1000,10))`

Without looping, I want to return the results of this loop

```
dfarray2=array(NA,dim=c(1,1000,10))

for(i in 1:10){

dfarray2[,,i]=mat%*%dfarray[,,i]


}
```

Comment: You might want to try the `tensor` packages.

Comment: `Error in mat %*% dfarray[, , i] : non-conformable arguments`. Is it `t(mat)`?

Comment: Neal I knew it would not be necessary to go to the tensor packages since the left matrix is the same, but thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility: deform the `dfarray` to usual matrix, multiply and transform back to 3d array.

```
mat <- matrix(1, 1, 13)
dim(dfarray) <- c(13, 1000*10)
dfarray1 <- mat %*% dfarray
dim(dfarray1) <- c(1, 1000, 10)
all(dfarray1==dfarray2)
[1] TRUE
```