# Multiply multidimensional array with same-sized matrix

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I'd like to multiply each matrix (13x10) of an array (13x10x10) `dfarray = array((1),dim=c(13,10,10))` with another matrix of the same size (13x10) `mat=matrix(2,13,10)`.

I tried the approach posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970514/multiply-each-matrix-slice-in-a-3d-array-by-a-single-matrix-in-r), but after `dfarray1 <- mat %*% dfarray` (after changing the dimensions as described in the post mentioned) the length changes (1300 vs. 1000) as well as the dimensions of my array.

I feel like I'm on the right track but somehow the last bit is missing.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you heard of [`tensorA`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tensorA/index.html) package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in order to do element-wise matrix multiplication.

```
#initiate new array with above dimensions
newarray <- array(1, dim=c(13,10,10))

#populate each matrix of the array
for (i in 1:10){
  newarray[, , i] <- dfarray[, , i] * mat
}
```

Output:

```
> dim(newarray)
[1] 13 10 10
```

Or as an alternative way as per @DavidArenburg 's comment just:

```
newarray[] <- apply(dfarray, 3, `*`, mat)
```

Comment: Or just ```newarray[] <- apply(dfarray, 3, `%*%`, mat)```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yeah this one is good too. I find that using a for-loop is easier for someone to understand the concept. Do you want me to add to my answer or do you want to post as a new one? In terms of speed it should be the same I suppose (or the for-loop slightly faster) since `apply` is base-R.

Comment: I guess you can edit your answer, as I'm not entirely sure that this is what OP after.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I just realised that I wrote my question the "wrong" way around. I meant multiplying an array (13x10x10) with a matrix of 13x10. Sorry, edited my question earlier but somehow didn't get through.

Comment: @Alex Your mat is of 10x13 dimensions (and not 13x10). The array is of 13x10x10. The result of multiplying the two will be an array of 13x13x10. My answer does exactly that.

Comment: @Lyzander Strange, it should be the same nrow and ncol in both
> dim(dfarray)
[1] 13 10 10
> dim(mat)
[1] 13 10

Comment: I am starting to believe that you do not need an algebra matrix multiplication but an element wise multiplication. Multiplying two matrices with the `%*%` is different to multiplying two matrices with the `*` operator. Do you want to do matrix algebra multiplication or element wise multiplication. If you want the second then your `mat` matrix should be of 13x10 dimensions and not of 10x13 dimensions (which is currently). Please change your `mat` object in your question accordingly.

Comment: @Alex Ok now I saw your edit. If you mat is of 13x10 dimensions then you can only do an element wise multiplication and not an algebra matrix multiplication. The operator you need is `*`. I updated my answer

Comment: @Alex Try my answer now

Comment: @LyzandeR Excellent, that was what I was looking for. Tried a similar loop before but didn't specify the dim for newarray!

Comment: @Alex Great! Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

`sweep` also comes to the rescue here. For a one line alternative without initialisation you can do:

```r
newarray <- sweep(x=dfarray, MARGIN=c(1, 2), STATS=mat, FUN='*')
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sweep), this will multiply dfarray by mat in the first and second dimensions.

You can even set `check.margin = TRUE` to check your array size and speed up execution