# R Apply Array Output Dimension

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, apply

Related to this question: [Multiply multidimensional array with same-sized matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369367/multiply-multidimensional-array-with-same-sized-matrix)

If I create the following array and matrix:

```
a <- array(1, dim=c(2,2,3))
b <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1), nrow=2)
```

and would like to carray out an elementwise multiplication of `b` with each slice of `a` moving along the 3rd dimension, I would use `apply`. However, I get the following strange result:

```
> dim(apply(a, 3, `*`, b))
[1] 4 3
> newa <- array(0, dim=c(2,2,3))
> newa[] <- apply(a, 3, `*`, b)
> dim(newa)
[1] 2 2 3
```

Why do these two things give different answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting dimension of `apply(a, 3,`*`, b)` is `4 3` because according to the documentation, see `?apply`:

> If each call to `FUN` returns a vector of length `n`, then `apply` returns an array of dimension `c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])` if `n > 1`.

In this case, each call to `FUN` returns a vector of length `4` and the dimension with `MARGIN=3` is `3`. Note that the results of each call of `FUN` in `apply` is coerced to a `vector` not a `matrix`.

Now, with `newa[] <- array(...`, you are replacing the values in the `newa` object with the values from the `array` computation. The attributes of `newa` is not changed, so its dimensions is still `2 2 3`.

Hope this helps.